# How to comment Android's Activities with JavaDoc?

Tags: android, javadoc

Activities are called in this way (an example):

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra("par1", "value1"); 
i.putExtra("par2", 2);
startActivityForResult(i);
```

How can I comment MyActivity class with JavaDoc like methods?

For example in this case:

```
/**
* This activity show some data
* @param par1 String value of parameter1
* @param par2 int number of records to show
* @return returnValue boolean true if data is showed, false otherwise
*/
```

to have an idea of which parameters intent expects and what type of return offers.

Answer (score 2):

Just write the JavaDoc part right in top of the class declaration.

```
    /**
    * JavaDoc
    */      
    public class MyActivity {
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I'm using now, I'm asking for the best practice to do that. Maybe is this

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on a Method Name-> Source-> Generate Element Comment.

Shortcut

```
ALT+SHIFT+J
```

Comment: param is used for method not class. your requirement serves method only not class, classes do not  have parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare the parameter constants as `public static final String` and add javadoc field documentation there.
2. Use `@link`s to bind things together.

Example:

```
/**
* String containing foo parameter for {@link #XyzzyActivity}
*/
public static final String EXTRA_FOO = "par1";

/**
* XyzzyActivity
*
* Parameters understood: {@link #EXTRA_FOO}, ...
*
* Returns...
*/
```

Comment: I did it, but it is interesting the way you used to link the constant to the class javadoc. I think that your solution merget with Markus_EI solution could be the best way

Answer (score 0):

Type `/**` at the top of your method, then press ENTER key. The comment part will become something like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
```

You are also allowed to add

```
@author – who wrote this code
@version – when was it changed
@param – describe method parameters
@return – describe method return values
@throws – describe exceptions thrown
@see – link to other, related items (e.g. “See also…”)
@since – describe when code was introduced (e.g. API Level)
@deprecated - describe deprecated item and what alternative to use instead
```